# Vuetify: Add Button or Link to Expansion Panel Header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Self-explanatory in title: how to add a button or a link inside the header of the vuetify expansion panel component?

When clicking the link or button, the expansion panel default behavior should not engage.

Comment: just add `.stop` [modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) like so `@click.stop`

Answer (score 10):

Using **@click.native.stop** 
Example

```
<v-btn fab white small color="white" class="button-payment"
   @click.native.stop="onDoSomeThing">Do something</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 6):

By using `@click.native.stop` on button or link inside expansion panel header it will trigger your click and will prevent the default behavior of expansion panel.